# Angular controller - Unable to display value

Tags: angularjs

This should be a very easy question for most of you guys, but i'm a beginner with angular..

So, i'm trying to display a progressbar (just as a test for the moment) but i'm unable to update the value.

An example can be found here: http://jsbin.com/cuvedoteye/edit?html,output

Here's the controller code:

```
.controller('test', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.progress = function () {
            var display = 100 * (Date.now() % 60) / 60;
            return display;
        }
    }])
```

and here's the html:

```
<h3>ProgressBar</h3>
<progress ng-controller="test" value="progress()"></progress>
```

why it's not working? thanks for any help

**EDIT**

Updated code with ng-value instead of value:
http://jsbin.com/jujewiboya/edit?html,output

I can see it moving in here, but in on my example i can't, it's just fully blue

Comment: where did <progress> come from? have you defined a directive somewhere?

Comment: progress is a html 5 tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_progress.asp

Comment: oh ok. i wasn't aware of that tag. Let me try to see whats wrong with your code then.

Comment: No problem :) thank you

Comment: how is the progress bar meant to work? change value to ng-value.

Comment: function `progress` runs only onсe - when controller created. Try to use `$interval`. Here's [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/QowKgpTcDCSjp2Fk45Mj) with directive and `$interval`.

Comment: @KovalenkoIvan thank you. This is actually working now. Please create an answer so that i can select it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `progress` runs only onсe - when controller created.

Try to use `$interval`. Here's [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/QowKgpTcDCSjp2Fk45Mj) with directive and `$interval`.

Answer (score 2):

You got to change `value` to `ng-value`.

```
<h3>ProgressBar</h3>
<progress ng-controller="test" ng-value="progress()"></progress>
```

Here is a [js-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kdth45q9/)

Comment: if i change it to ng-value, i'm not able to see it moving. Why?

Comment: Ok. What you are trying to do is not that easily achievable. I would rather use css animation for simulating loading. Is that a option?

Comment: yes, i mean, i'm just doing some proof of concept before starting my real project, i thought it would have been this easy, but i can evaluate different options without any problem

Comment: the strange thing tho, is that in the second jsbin link in my question, it work as i want, but it does not in my project for some reason that i cannot understand

Answer (score 1):

Try ng-value attribute instead of value in the  tag

Comment: with ng-value i can see something in the value tag, but i actually wanted to see the bar moving...all i have is a full progressbar. Is it something that i have to change in the controller function?

Comment: could you please to try define max attr too?

Comment: actually, if i add ng-value in the jsbin link above i can see it moving, but on my code it's not moving for some reason..

Comment: Also your progress() function call will reset progress on each call.

Comment: I think it shouldn`t move at all when value attr is set. If you wish to see moveing, you need increment this value

Comment: Please check my edited question. That's the behave i'd like to see in my app as well, but instead, the progressbar is static

Comment: You can see it moving in your jsbin cause it seems that it is launched without js. So value for progress tag is not set. And it is default behavior -- if no value set. If you hit "run with js" button it won`t move at all.

Comment: ok, yes. If i uncheck run with javascript it is exactly what i have in my project

Comment: @Nick, according to tag name, it should show a progress. So it can't show moving, when you set the value. You can increment the value so it will show the progress == value/max * 100. You can see full progress bar because you haven`t specify max attr. So the max == value.